# nyromodal iframe size problem

Tags: jquery, nyromodal

I have a jquery gallery (galleriffic), which opened nyroModal and a good set size.
I want to post pictures on this page (page open with nyromodal where is gallery).
When I use an iframe, the page size has the wrong value.

jquery code used on the gallery.aspx, which is run as a nyromodal:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var height = $(window).height();
        var width = $(window).width();
        alert(height);
        alert(width);
        var autosizable = true;
        var windowResize = true;
        var resizeable = true;

        $.nyroModalSettings({
            bgColor: '#000000',
            windowResize: windowResize,
            width: width,
            height: height,
            resizable: resizeable,
            autoSizable: autosizable
        });
    });
```

link opens the gallery page (a little distorted because I did not want me to display a html):

*a class="nyroModal" target="_blank" href='Ajax/gallery.aspx?guid=<%= Trip.guid%>&op=add'**img src="~/img/icon/icon_add.gif" runat="server" /**/a*

How to set good size to this gallery??
When i will put the value of the stiffness does not interpret them

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Nyro javascript file and search for -> "boxModel" (please notice the cAsE-sEnsItIviTy). You will find **two places** where there is a `99%` height used. I had to change that to `100%`.